# Meteor publish Collections up to a maximum of 1000 items

Tags: meteor

I read again and again that you should not publish large collections at Meteor. What is the situation like this:

A user has a table of a maximum of 1000 articles.

So in the worst case, he loads a collection of 1000 docs. This collection is split on the client side by a table with pagination. Since the user has loaded all his articles, he can quickly search, filter and sort articles. If I now use a pagination in a publish method, the user has to wait a moment for each action and the implementation is a longer process (some functions in the app affect all articles of the user). Is a single publish of max 1000 items still portable, or is the ram and the cpu loaded so high that this is a bad idea?

Comment: This is primarily an opinion-based question and as such is likely to get closed. 1000 1KB items (1MB total) might be no problem. A 1000 1MB documents (i.e. 1GB) is a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Ok interesting, thank you

Comment: are you using blaze or another view layer? if you use blaze you could do template level sub with client generated query. I do it that way with infinite scroll style. Some functions in the app affects all articles but methods are (should be) in the server-side so it wouldn't really matter

Comment: That's mainly the reason I ask. I use angular-meteor and am quite happy with it, but most cool packs were written for Blaze. I just change my code just as you have just described it. I would, however, generally interest a maximum. For example, the case set a doc would only have a Boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

I've been to the position that you're at now. So, I did a performance testing. Trying to send 2000 documents to the client to see what happens.

> Result: My server reported high CPU usages and the client browser hanged, literally.

And I had to use the pagination method, where server would send the data as required.

In case you also find the need to use pagination by server, [EasySearch](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) is a nice package which handles all of that very nicely. Minimal lags.

Hope it helps you.